# Pooling RestTemplante setReadTimeout

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate, apache-httpclient-5.x

I need to create a pool of connectors using **apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1*** and SpringBoot(ver 3.1.5) RestTemplate.

This code works correctly:

```
private static RestTemplate pooledRestTemplate() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(2000);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(2000);
    
        HttpClient httpClient =
            HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();
    
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .build();
      }
```

But if I add `.setReadTimeout()` to the builder:

```
 return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .build();
```

When the application starts, an error message appears:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request factory org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory has the setReadTimeout method marked as deprecated
```

I read about this moment when updating the version https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35658.
But I didn't understand how to combine the pool of connectors and RestTemplateBuilder.